# how to configuring certificate validation in amazon app runner

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-app-runner

When I tried to link my app in App Runner to my route 53 domain got these two steps:

1. Configure certificate validation (has two records names and values)
2. Configure DNS target (has on record and one value)

I got how to do step 2 but could not figure out step one (where to add these names and values).

I have a certificate in AWS certificate manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You add the records to your DNS server, just like how you did step 2.

See [Associate (link) a custom domain to your service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apprunner/latest/dg/manage-custom-domains.html) for details docs.

> When you associate a custom domain with your service, App Runner provides you with a set of CNAME records serve for certificate validation purpose. You must add these CNAME records to your Domain Name System (DNS) server. Add the certificate validation records, provided by App Runner, to your DNS server. This way, App Runner can validate that you own or control the domain.